# How to avoid StaleElementReferenceException error in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

There are tons of questions about this error however none of them could be able to help my case.

First i get the main url's ids that i need

```
url = 'http://www.mosquedirectory.co.uk/browse/uk/england/london'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

listing = browser.find_elements_by_id('directory_listingBrowse')
```

and I append them in to list to avoid from the error but it is not even worked

```
hold = []

for i in listing:
    hold.append(i)
```

and from these hold list I loop in for loop and this is also the rest of the code

```
for i in hold:
     
    try: ulclass = i.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul.c')

    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass
        
    link = []
    for i in ulclass:
        a = i.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        link.append(a.get_attribute('href'))
        
    for i in link:
        browser.get(i)

    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
```

I even tried to avoid the error by using try method, not worked again. And at the end of the code I say get back to old page, again to avoid the error. It's not even worked again. Which part am I missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight change of approach. Collect all links first, then process them as you wish.

```
url = 'http://www.mosquedirectory.co.uk/browse/uk/england/london'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

listings = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='directory_listingBrowse']//ul//*//a[@href]")))

all_links = [listing.get_attribute('href') for listing in listings]

for link in all_links:
    browser.get(link)
    #do whatever else here
```

Don't forget to add these imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139)s you can store the *textContents*. Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.mosquedirectory.co.uk/browse/uk/england/london")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#directory_listingBrowse h2 a")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.mosquedirectory.co.uk/browse/uk/england/london")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='directory_listingBrowse']//h2//a")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Barking and Dagenham (10)', 'Barnet (13)', 'Bexley (2)', 'Brent (26)', 'Bromley (4)', 'Camden (20)', 'City of London (8)', 'Croydon (17)', 'Ealing (20)', 'Enfield (10)', 'Greenwich (7)', 'Hackney (21)', 'Hammersmith and Fulham (14)', 'Haringey (12)', 'Harrow (11)', 'Havering (4)', 'Hertforshire (1)', 'Hillingdon (8)', 'Hounslow (9)', 'Islington (17)', 'Kensington and Chelsea (12)', 'Kingston upon Thames (2)', 'Lambeth (16)', 'Lewisham (3)', 'Loughton (1)', 'Merton (7)', 'Middlesex (21)', 'Newham (59)', 'Redbridge (25)', 'Richmond upon Thames (1)', 'Romford (4)', 'Southwark (13)', 'Sutton (4)', 'Tower Hamlets (76)', 'Waltham Forest (21)', 'Wandsworth (9)', 'Westminster (27)']
  ```